# Routing Symfony : Locale is ignored

Tags: symfony

Here is the context : I have a multi country website and i have an url which is the same between France and Belgium website but I want them to redirect to different actions.
Here is a simple sample of my controller :

```
    /**
     * @Route({
     *     "fr": "/over-ons",
     *     "be": "/about-us"
     * }, name="about_us")
     */
    public function about()
    {
        die("about");
    }


    /**
     * @Route({
     *     "fr": "/about-us",
     *     "be": "/over-ons"
     * }, name="about_us_2")
     */
    public function about2()
    {
        die("about 2");
    }
```

Then, i created a LocaleSubscriber (based on https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html) :

```
<?php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'en')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = 'fr';
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $request->setDefaultLocale($this->defaultLocale);
        $request->setLocale($this->defaultLocale);
        $request->attributes->set('_locale', $this->defaultLocale);
        $routeParams = $request->attributes->get('_route_params');
        $routeParams['_locale'] = $this->defaultLocale;
        $request->attributes->set('_route_params', $routeParams);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 20]],
        ];
    }
}
```

Then i opened http://localhost/about-us and wanted to see the message "about 2" but i have "about".

So the road "about-us" with locale "fr" shoud be matched with about2 action but it matches with about action.

Do you kown if it is possible that the Router match a route with a specific locale please ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

It won't work like that.

The router will match request to the first matching route. So at that point it has very little to do with locale.

A request comes in with the path of `/about-us`, and it is matched to the about action with the `be` locale, because that route is defined first.

If you want to use the same route names for multiple locales you will have to add the locale to the URL. Subdomain, prefix, etc, doesn't really matter.

For example:
`fr/about-us`
`be/about-us`

(Of course you don't need to do it one by one, define it as a prefix in YAML)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.